# Iterating through text with a different length delay between them

Tags: java, loops, runnable, bukkit

- Bukkit / Spigot API - https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/
  Okay, I'm trying to make a tutorial system for my server. I've often seen people displaying text like this:

  ```
  public void send(String...strings) {
      for (String string : strings) {
          player.sendMessage(string);
      }
  }
  ```

  .. which is terrible. As you know, it'd spam the chat and make it un-readable.
  So instead, I'm using runnables to display the text in a certain delay. I could easily make a runnable with the same specific delay (i.e 30 ticks), but I'd love the runnable to have the delay based on the length() of the String.

  I tried to do it like this:

  ```
  public void send(String...strings) {
      for (String string : strings) {
          new BukkitRunnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  player.sendMessage(string);
              }
          }.runTaskLater(my_plugin_instance, (string.length()*2));
      }
  }
  ```

  With this, yes, it takes the lenght of the string, but the `for loop` continues to the next String before the runnable has displayed the text.
  So If I had these sentences for example (in the correct order):

  - `Welcome to the server, player!`
  - `This server is about blablabla, this and that and a bit more of that and this`
  - `Accept the tutorial?`

  The order will be

  - `Accept the tutorial?`
  - `Welcome to the server, player!`
  - `This server is about blablabla, this and that and a bit more of that and this`

  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider having a one single object (ie. Singleton) that acts as a printer to print all messages. This will avoid creating too many threads.

The solution below uses BlockingQueue in order to make the printing thread wait for next message. When the message is not in the queue - run() method will wait without consuming much CPU.

The solution comes in two flavors:
- if you uncomment first msgQueue - you will get blocking behavior of sendMessage; the method will wait until all items are printed.
- if you uncommend second msgQueue - the messages will be added to the queue without waiting to print.

I added ExecutorService to manage Thread as Oracle/Java sees that as a good practice to manage threads using ExecutorServices. Once MessagePrinter is not needed - it is signalled by "executor.shutdownNow();" and finishes peacefully.

Hope this helps.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class MessagePrinter implements Runnable {

    private static MessagePrinter instance;
    private MessagePrinter() {};

    // Uncomment the one below to make sendText wait until methods until all items are printed:
    // BlockingQueue<String> msgQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1);

    // Uncomment the one below to make sendText not wait until messages are printed:
    BlockingQueue<String> msgQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1);

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) { 
                String str = msgQueue.take();
                Thread.sleep( str.length() );
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep( str.length() * 10 );

                System.out.println(str);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Quitting...");
            return;
        }
    }

    public void sendText(String... txt) {
        Arrays.asList(txt).stream().forEach(t -> {
            try {
                msgQueue.put(t);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Received request to terminate.
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    synchronized public static MessagePrinter getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new MessagePrinter();
        return instance;
    }
}

public class VarDelay {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        MessagePrinter msp = MessagePrinter.getInstance(); 

        executor.submit(msp);

        msp.sendText(new String[] {"Welcome to the server, player!",
                "This server is about blablabla, this and that and a bit more of that and this",
                "Accept the tutorial?" });

        msp.sendText("More text to follow");

        // Shutdown:
        executor.shutdown();
        if (!executor.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, nobody replied.. Ended up solving it myself, but I'm not proud of the code. Had to use 2 runnables.. 

In case someone is interested, I'll leave the code here.

```
public void send(Player player,  long delay, String basecolor, String... strings) {
    List<String> str = Arrays.asList(strings);
    new BukkitRunnable() {
        int ind = 0;
        boolean next = true;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String s = str.get(ind);
            if (next) {
                next = false;
                Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(YOUR_PLUGIN_INSTANCE, new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&',
                                    basecolor + s.replace("%p", player.getName()).replace("%s", server_name)));
                        next = true;
                    }
                }, (ind == 0 ? 0 : (str.get(ind - 1).length())));
                if (ind + 1 < str.size()) {
                    ind++;
                } else {
                    cancel();
                }
            }
        }
    }.runTaskTimer(YOUR_PLUGIN_INSTANCE, delay, 10);
}
```

This could be used as follows, as an example:

`send(player, 30, "&a", "Welcome to %s, %p!", "Enter the stuff you want to show here!", "They're all in the right order!");`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply sth like this:

```
private void send(final Player player, String...messages) {

    long delaySum = 0;

    for (final String message : messages) {
        Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                player.sendMessage(message);
            }
        };

        this.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(this, myTask, delaySum);
        delaySum += message.length() * 2;
    }
}
```

this way, every message gets dalayed by all the delays calculated before.

**Attention: This has not been tested**